# VPN Encryption Domain

Tags: vpn, domain, encryption, site-to-site-vpn

I'm trying to connect to a counterparty using VPN IPsec. I have a standard cable broadband connection with a single static IP address.
The counterparty have asked me for my "Public IP Address Assigned to VPN Device" and also my "Encryption Domain".

What exactly is an encryption domain? (Is this my internal IP address of the host machine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encryption domain refers to the range of IP addresses of the hosts which will be participating in the encrypted VPN.